# How to connect Java Class through Soap to InDesign cs6 Server? (Don't Use Command Line arguments.)

Tags: java, soap, indesign-server

How to connect Java Class (client side) through Soap to InDesign cs6 Server? (Don't Use Command Line arguments.)